# VPS-сервер не виден извне

Tags: linux, debian, vps

Купил VPS-сервер. Поставил туда сайт на Flask, который хорошо работал на локальной машине. При попытке подключиться к серверу извне, оказалось, что он недоступен, притом программа для хоста сайта запущена. Пытался сменить порт в программе, не помогло.

`Iptables` выдает это

```
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: роутер во внутреннюю сеть не пускает. разрешите в нём нужный порт.

Comment: Роутоер не мой. Порт разрешил, но без результатов

Comment: А к самому серверу как подключаешься-то?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение. Вместо `iptables` установил `ufw` и одобрил нужные порты с указанием протокола, заработало.